# Delphi Convert TArray<Strings> to DateTime

Tags: delphi, pascal

I want to convert all the values contained in a TArray to TDateTime type.
ConvertDS and ConvertDE are TDateTime variable and StoringData is the TArray

```
StoringData : TArray<String>;
SetLength(StoringData,2);
  for x := 0 to High(StoringData) do
    for c := 0 to  High(StoringData[x]) do
      begin
         StoringData[x]   :=  TotTime;
         StoringData[c]   :=  DataCovertedS;
      end;


ConvertDS := (StrToDateTime(StoringData[c]));
ConvertDE := (StrToDateTime(StoringData[c+1]));
```

Data is splitted like this

```
        Year  := Copy(aData,0,4);
        Month := Copy(aData,5,2);
        Day   := Copy(aData,7,2);
        DataCovertedS := Concat(Year+'-'+Month+'-'+Day);
```

When i try to execute it the StrToDateTime doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide the full code in order to allow us to understand your question.

Comment: You forgot to tell us the most important thing! What type is `StoringData[i]`? Equivalently, what type is `StoringData`? For instance, if `StoringData` is a `TArray<string>`, then `StoringData[i]` is a `string`. The fact that you have an array is irrelevant; what matters is the values.

Comment: Thank you for your update. So we know they are strings. But we also must know their format. Is it `2021-05-31 15:00:00` or `31/5 2021 15.00 am` etc? In general, converting strings to datetimes is not possible, even for a human, so that is an operation you typically avoid. And if you cannot avoid it, you need to settle for a very precise format.

Comment: (Also, your line `for c := 0 to  High(StoringData[x]) do` is clearly nonsensical, `Concat(Year+'-'+Month+'-'+Day);` can be written `Year+'-'+Month+'-'+Day;`, and instead of doing `Copy` and `+`, you should use `FormatDateTime` or similar.)

Comment: @AntonioPetricca More information added

Comment: Anyhow, your actual question is "How to obtain a `TDateTime` value from a string in the format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`", right?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes, i want to convert not the single string YYYY-MM-DD but all the TArray<Strings> to TDateTime

Comment: @Marcol1no: Yes, so then you must know (1) how to convert a string in the format YYYY-MM-DD to a date and (2) how to iterate an array. These are two entirely different questions.

Comment: I mean, if you want to paint five houses, you first need to learn (1) how to paint a house, and then (2) how to transport yourself to the five sites. You can ask a painter "Can you teach me how to paint a house?", but if you ask him "Can you, specifically, tell me how to paint five houses?" he might not take you too seriously! :)

Comment: I strongly suggest you buy a good book about programming in general and Delphi programming in particular, because everything gets so much easier if you know the basics you need to know. The books by Marco Cantu are generally regarded as good and up to date.

Comment: You seems that you want to store the conversion result in the same TArray<String>. That is not possible. The array has only strings. You can use two different arrays: one for string values and one for TDateTime values. Or an array of record, the record having two parts: one string and one TDateTime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that the actual question is "How to obtain a `TDateTime` value from a string in the format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`?".

Fortunately, this is not hard. Every time you use a new function in an API, you read its documentation. In this case, the [`StrToDate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrToDate) documentation says the following:

> `S` must consist of two or three numbers, separated by the character defined by the `DateSeparator` global variable or its `TFormatSettings` equivalent. The order for month, day, and year is determined by the `ShortDateFormat` global variable or its `TFormatSettings` equivalent--possible combinations are m/d/y, d/m/y, and y/m/d.

So, we can do it like this:

```pascal
// Define the date format:
var FS := TFormatSettings.Invariant;
FS.DateSeparator := '-';
FS.ShortDateFormat := 'y/m/d';

// Just an example of a string in this format:
const S = '2021-05-31';

// StrToDate will parse this using FS:
var D := StrToDate(S, FS);

// Test:
ShowMessage(DateToStr(D));
```